# Why is WM_CLOSE not handled automatically by DefDlgProc?

Tags: winapi, modal-dialog, dialog

When I create a dialog using [`DialogBox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645452%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), it won't close unless I handle WM_CLOSE in my own `DLGPROC` function and call `EndDialog`.

I know that this is by design, but I'm interested why was it chosen for WM_CLOSE not to be handled automatically by DefDlgProc? Are there any good reasons for that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ask yourself this:

What would the default handling of WM_CLOSE be? Calling `EndDialog`? I think EndDialog would only work in very rare situations.

Other suggestions:

- validating user input in the dialog, showing errors if input is out-of-range or otherwise not valid, **not ending the dialog**
- closing child windows, releasing resources/memory that child windows of the dialog are using, releasing COM-Objects, basically: cleaning up first and then end the dialog.

Comment: So by making the default behavior intentionally buggy (dialog doesn't close even when you press the close button), they're trying to attract the attention of the developer to handling WM_CLOSE explicitly, in order to prevent more subtle bugs later on?

Comment: Yes. Imagine it would automatically close, but you didn't save whatever the user entered or worked on. Apps (and therefore dialogs) should always ask the user first to save the work before closing down.